# What are the advantages and disadvantages of certain radial symmetries in spacecraft construction?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, spacecraft, engineering, construction

I'm mainly considering the merits and drawbacks of threefold versus fourfold (or higher, like sixfold and eightfold) radial symmetries when it comes to the construction of a fuselage for a spacecraft designed for interplanetary trips.

It *appears* to me that fourfold construction (or a multiple of it) is optimal, barring going for a completely cylindrical shape for optimal surface area to volume ratio. This is particularly pertinent to a reaction control system perspective, wherein it seems trivially easy to simply place thrusters at 90 degrees to each other with no real need for directional thrust control, creating a system with fewer moving parts and thus a lower failure rate, though appearances can be deceiving.

This is just one possible advantage, though, and there could be other advantages to a threefold or sixfold radial symmetry construction that aren't immediately apparent to me that are beneficial enough to warrant choosing them over a simplified RCS.

Comment: I've added the crewed-spaceflight tag because I think you are taking about long mission spacecraft with pressurized crew cabins rather than interplanetary probes which are more like giant fuel tanks with a bunch of sensors and antennas stuck to them. Is that correct?

Comment: Your example with the RCS only fits unless you come to the point of redundancy. If you want a system that survives if one thruster fails, you end up with a tetrahedral arrangement.

Comment: @uhoh Yes, that would be correct, thanks for the added tags!

Comment: @asdfex Something like this? http://clowder.net/hop/tetships/tetships.html